# Nuxt 3 build generates 500 i18n[TranslateVNodeSymbol] is not a function error, but works in dev mode

Tags: nuxt.js, internationalization, nuxtjs3, vue-i18n, nuxt-i18n

In my `package.json` file I have `"@nuxtjs/i18n": "^8.0.0-rc.5"` installed

I have the following code in the `nuxt.config.ts` file

```
modules: ["@nuxtjs/i18n"],
  build: {
    transpile: ["vue-i18n"],
  },
  i18n: {
    vueI18n: "./i18n.config.ts",
  },
  vite: {
    plugins: [
      VueI18nVitePlugin({
        include: [
          resolve(dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url)), "./locales/*.json"),
        ],
      }),
    ],
    css: {
      preprocessorOptions: {
        scss: {
          additionalData: "@use \"@/assets/styles/_variables.scss\" as *;",
        },
      },
    },
  },
```

When running `npm run dev` command, everything works totally fine.

However, when I run `npm run build` or `npm run preview` commands, the build finishes without errors, but when I open it up, I see the error related to the i18n module.
[production build error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGoAG.jpg)
[npm run build result in terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBlyn.png)

The content of the `i18n.config.ts` file:

```
import ru from "~/locales/ru.json"
import en from "~/locales/en.json"

export default defineI18nConfig(() => ({
  legacy: false,
  globalInjection: true,
  locale: "ru",
  messages: {
    ru,
    en,
  },
}))
```

Comment: What if you run the node command given after the build (2nd screenshot)?

Comment: @kissu It starts the server with a message **Listening on http://[::]:3000**, but when I try to open it in browser I still see the same **500 error i18n[TranslateVNodeSymbol]** is not a function